# How to use custom alert in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, alert

I've created a custom alert as a component in React Native. I used `Modal` to create this custom alert. My problem is, how to use it? Instead of using `Alert.alert` in React Native, I want to display my own alert.

Here is my `Custom Alert Modal`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

import styles from './style';
import Button from '../../components/Button';

export default class CustomAlert extends Component {

  renderModalContent = () => (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.contentInfo}>{this.props.content}</Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          color={this.props.buttonColor}
          text={this.props.buttonText}
          onPress={this.props.buttonOnPress}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          isVisible={this.props.isVisible}
          backdropColor="#000000"
          backdropOpacity={0.9}
          animationIn="zoomInDown"
          animationOut="zoomOutUp"
          animationInTiming={600}
          animationOutTiming={600}
          backdropTransitionInTiming={600}
          backdropTransitionOutTiming={600}
        >
          {this.renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is how I want to use it. I want to display this alert through a function. That means when function catches up with an error, I want to show my custom alert.

```
myFunction()
  .then(() => // do something)
  .catch(() => // show my custom alert);
```

Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set isVisible true in your catch block.

```
myFunction()
 .then(() => // do something)
 .catch((e) => this.setState({ isVisible: true }))
```

Comment: Should I add my custom alert modal inside my screen's `render()` function as well?

Comment: @SennenRandika yes and pass `isVisible` as a prop

Comment: My screen's `render()` function has two returns. One is the activity indicator. The other return is the screen view. So, should I add my `custom alert` into both of these returns inside the `render()` function?

Comment: it's hard for me to say without seeing the whole code, try adding it to both returns and see if it works.

Comment: It worked then. Thank you for your answer. Now, another thing. Sometimes, the alert should be displayed while returning the activity indicator. Sometimes, the alert should be displayed while returning the screen's view. Is there any solution for this rather than adding my custom alert inside both returns?

Comment: you can use condtional rendering and use one return statement.

Comment: Got it!! Hope this will solve my problem. Thanks for your answer.